# GridListTile / Lazy Image loading / Images not vertical entered

Tags: material-ui

Gridlist will automaticaly center and crop images when scaled down to the squared view. This is only supported for image tags.

```html
<GridListTile key={tile.img}>
   <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
</GridListTile>
```

How can I replace this image with [React Lazy Load Image Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component) without loosing this behaviour:

```html
<GridListTile key={tile.img}>
   <LazyLoadImage
      alt={image.alt}
      height={image.height}
      src={image.src} // use normal <img> attributes as props
      width={image.width} />
</GridListTile>
```